# How to get started with implementing my own VGP code for iPhone OpenGL ES development?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

How do I get started with implementing my own Vertex Geometry Processor code for iPhone OpenGL ES development, in order to fully benefit from its VGP Lite chip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone chip can only be used for fixed-function processing as part of the normal transform and lighting pipeline. There's no way to run custom vertex programs.